# Возможно ли сделать так, чтоб по истечении определенного срока запись удалялась из postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, хранимые-процедуры

Предположим у меня есть запись в postgres, в одном из полей которого лежит дата и время, когда запись станет не действительной.

Можно ли внутри самой субд повесить некий колбек, чтоб запись удалялась по истечению срока жизни?

Comment: Похоже нужно смотреть в сторону шедулеров для Postgre - https://severalnines.com/database-blog/overview-job-scheduling-tools-postgresql

Comment: В чистой версии вроде как нет встроенного планировщика задач (scheduler), но используются внешние средства: планировщики ОС, доустановка PgAgent или что-то еще.

Comment: Встроенных механизмов нет, но есть расширение https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron